# Sort excel list with blocks consisted of data that will not be sorted

Tags: excel, sorting

I have an excel file that contains one column with thousands of rows with data.

I need to sort this list in the next fashion:

I want to keep the data in chunks of 20 rows, and then sort those chunks in reverse order.
Here is more specific example:

Let’s say I have a list with 60 rows:

1

…

20

21

…

40

41

…

60

This list consists of 3 chunks of 20 rows:  1-20, 21-40 and 41-60. The data inside these chunks should not be sorted.

Now I need to sort these 3 chunks in reverse order, so my final list will look like:

41

…

60

21

…

40

1

…

20

How do I approach this?

Comment: Add a helper column containing the chunks sequence and then sort.

Comment: I was thinking about it, how do I fill down that helper column for a thousands rows long list quick?

Comment: If interval is fixed, that should be easy. If not, can you further describe how you determine `chunking`?

Comment: Yes it will be always 20 rows intervals

Comment: Forget about the merger cause you cannot sort it. See my post for the detailed answer.

Comment: ok waiting for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this assuming your data is below:

[image: sampledata]

In `A2` use this formula:
`=ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/20,0)`

Then autofill down. It should give you your `20` cell chunk.
Copy and paste to values and then do your sorting.
Hope this helps.

**Result:**
[image: sampledata2]

Comment: thanks, that formula is exactly what I was looking for, you are the best!